# Need to remove a particular tag from published single post pages

Tags: support, tags

Single posts show tag or tags after content on my website. I need to remove a particular tag making it hidden from the page. Actually I have redirected a link to this so cannot delete. I googled but cannot find any function as everywhere codes for exclusion of a tag from cloud is available.

[image: remove a particular tag from published single post pages]

Comment: You have to find out how they got there. When you edit the page it has no tags set?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the response, leymannx. the code of the single page for showing tag/tags is as follow (swift is the theme name) -

```
    <?php if (has_tag()): ?>
        <div class="tags">
            <?php echo __('Tagged with', 'swift') . '&nbsp;'; ?>
            <h6>
                <?php the_tags('', ' ', ' '); ?>
            </h6>
        </div>
```